# X11 errors with pygtk on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: python, pygtk, x11, osx-leopard

I have a python program that implements pygtk for GUI.  I have it running successfully on some MAC computers running os 10.6.*, after installing pygtk with macports.  I have just installed pygtk on a mac 10.5.8 system.  When I execute the program I get these errors:

> Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "/tmp/launch-CQ7og4/:0".

and

> ADP_2.1.py: Fatal IO error 35 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server /tmp/launch-CQ7og4/:0.

After this second error the program does not continue.  I looked at the /tmp/launch-CQ7og4/ directory and there is only ":0" in there.

On the other Macs that run this program the first Xlib warning always appears but the program still runs seemingly correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `X11-2.6.*`

Comment: It Worked! I downloaded the installer from here : http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.6.0